# Google Maps geojson markers cluster can't be clicked for info

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I am attempting to place markers from a geojson file and allow them to be clickable for more info (infowindow).

Here's my code

```
<script>
var map, infoWindow, trafficLayer;

function toggleTraffic(){
    if(trafficLayer.getMap() == null){
        //traffic layer is disabled.. enable it
        trafficLayer.setMap(map);
    } else {
        //traffic layer is enabled.. disable it
        trafficLayer.setMap(null);             
    }
}

function initMap() {

function loadJSON(callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'mapdark.json', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    };
    xobj.send(null);
}

var loaded_json

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ });

loadJSON(function(response) {
    loaded_json = JSON.parse(response);

    var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(loaded_json, {
        name: 'Map'
    });

    var h=get_cookie('pos');
    if (h) {
        h=h.split(',');
        var lat=parseFloat(h[0]);
        var lng=parseFloat(h[1]);
        var zoom=parseInt(h[2]);
    } else {
        var lat=40;
        var lng=15;
        var zoom=7;
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{center:{lat:lat,lng:lng},zoom:zoom,gestureHandling:'greedy'});

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
    });

    map.data.loadGeoJson('../json/geo.php', null, function (features) {
        var markers = features.map(function(feature) {
            var g = feature.getGeometry();
            var iconurl = feature.getProperty('icon');
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
              'position': g.get(0) ,
              'icon': iconurl
            });
            return marker;
        });

        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,{ imagePath: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m' });    

    });

    map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
        var title = event.feature.getProperty("title");
        var address = event.feature.getProperty("address");
        var contentString = '<div style="width: 94.2%; padding-left:10px; height: 25px;float: left;color: #FFF;background: #0b3061;font-size: 16px;line-height: 25px;border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;"><strong><b>' + title + '</b></strong><br></div><br><div><p align="left"><b>Address: </b>' + address + '<br></div>';

        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);

        infowindow.setPosition(event.feature.getGeometry().get());

        infowindow.setOptions({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,-30)});

        infoWindow.open(map, anchor);

        map.setCenter(featurePosition); 

        console.log('test'); 
    });

    map.data.setStyle(function (feature) { return { icon: feature.getProperty('icon'), visible: false }; });

    map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);

    map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');

    //console.log(loaded_json)
    });

    function get_cookie(cname) {
        var name=cname+"=";
        var ca=document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i<ca.length;i++) {
            var c=ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
                c=c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name)==0) {
                return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
            }
        }
        return '';
    }  

}
</script>
```

I have also tried `marker.addListener('click', function(event)` instead of `map.data.addListener('click', function(event)` *but* `console.log('test');` doesn't show in the log either. Unfortunately, I'm not getting an error (nor on click) and most of the examples online show the geojson internally.

Clusters, markers, the style and positioning all work.

What am I missing to successfully show the infowindow?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, including sample GeoJSON data.

Comment: Why do I get downvoted for asking a legitimate question? This is not a markerCluster duplicate. Please read my question before assuming duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it is not working in your case but to make marker clickable you could add `click` event handler to `Marker` object like this:

```
var markers = features.map(function(feature) {
        var g = feature.getGeometry();
        var iconurl = feature.getProperty('icon');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
          'position': g.get(0) ,
          'icon': iconurl
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function (event) {
            infowindow.setContent("Marker");
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }); 


        return marker;
    });
```

Demo

```js
function initMap() {

    var dataUrl = "https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json";

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { center: { lat: -28, lng: 137 }, zoom: 4, gestureHandling: 'greedy' });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.close();
    });

    map.data.loadGeoJson(dataUrl, null, function (features) {
        var markers = [];
        features.forEach(function (feature) {
            var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getAt(0);
            var iconurl = feature.getProperty('icon');


            coordinates.forEachLatLng(function (latLng) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    'position': latLng,
                    'icon': iconurl
                });

                marker.addListener('click', function (event) {
                    infowindow.setContent("Marker");
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });


                markers.push(marker);
            });
        });

        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, { imagePath: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m' });

    });

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
 #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 640px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
  
  <div id="map"></div>
```

In case of *cluster marker*, to display info window once the marker is clicked attach `clusterclick` event handler like this:

```
 var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, { imagePath: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m',zoomOnClick: false });


  google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function (cluster) {
        infowindow.setPosition(cluster.getCenter());
        infowindow.setContent("Cluster marker");
        infowindow.open(map);
  });
```